# Can I start a remote connection on an other location from my own pc

Tags: remote-desktop, connection, remote

I have 2 pc's. Both running microsoft remote desktop. Now I want to start a remote dekstop connection on pc 2 of pc 1. I want to do this from pc 1. Is this possible with remote desktop or any other tool. The idea is that the view of pc 1 switches to pc 2, without doing anything on pc 2

Thanks

Comment: Could you please review your question ? I don't understand what you mean by 'the view of pc 1 switches to pc 2, without doing anything on pc 2'.

Comment: I have a windows 7 pc and a windows server 2008 R2. The screen of the server is above the screen of my windows 7 pc. What I want is a shortcut or something on my windows 7 that opens RDP on my server and connects with my windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I get it ! What you want is a RDP shortcut to open the RDP session to your server.

So, simply open the Remote Desktop Connection program (Run > mstsc). Fill in the required information (server name or IP, login, etc...). Some options appears by clicking the 'Show options' button.

Then, when all required informations are provided, you just have to click the 'Save as' button to create and save the shortcut.

[image]

Hope this helps !

Comment: What I want is that when I click the shortcut on my windows 7, rdp opens on my server and makes a connection with my windows 7. That way what I see on my windows 7 I can also see on my server screen.. So what I want is that my server screen contains the view of my windows 7 screen..

Comment: As RDP open the session, you can't have the same session opened locally and in RDP. So may I suggest the use of another tool, like VNC ?

Comment: Is it possible in VNC? That would be great!